# Bind a callback to directive through template tag in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, callback

I am trying to bind a callback to a component through a template. The template contains instance of another directive. This just doesn't seems to work. I'm invoking the directive from a modal, not sure if this can cause a problem. I tried many of the solution suggested in previous questions and still no luck. I ran it with a debugger, and the '$ctrl.onSelectionChanged' is defined to be as it should:

```
function (locals) { return parentGet(scope, locals); }
```

My code:

my-component.js:

The inner-directive as no reference to the callback, should it have?

```
angular.module('myModule')
.component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div class="container-fluid"> <inner-directive><button class="btn btn-default center-block" ng-click="$ctrl.onSelectionChange({items_list: $ctrl.selectedItems})">Button</button> </inner-directive> </div>',
    bindings: {
        $router: '<',
        onSelectionChange: '&'
    },
    controller: MyComponentController
});


/* @ngInject */
function MyComponentController(MyService, $filter, $log, $q) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$routerOnActivate = function () {

    };

    $ctrl.selectedItems = [];
}
```

calling-component-controller.js:

```
function CallingComponentCtrl(toastr, $scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.loadDone = false;

    $ctrl.grid = {
        enableSorting: true,
        data: [],
        columnDefs: [
            {name: 'id'},
            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'description'}
        ],
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        noUnselect: true,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $ctrl.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };

    this.$onInit = function () {
        if (angular.isUndefined($ctrl.abc)) {
            return;
        }
        syncData();
        $ctrl.loadDone = true;
    };

    this.$onChanges = function () {
        // TODO
    };

    function syncData(){
        $ctrl.grid.data = $ctrl.abc;
    }

   $ctrl.myFoo = function(items_list) {
        alert("This is never happening");
    };


 $ctrl.onPress = function (event) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            template: '<my-component on-selection-change="$ctrl.myFoo(items_list)"></my-component>',
            windowClass: 'modal-window'
        });
    };

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: could you add the complete code of **calling-component-controller.js**? and code of **MyComponentController**

Comment: Sure, I kept some stuff out since I can't publish it all. But all the related things are here.

Comment: if I understant it well, you are showing up a modal with the directive **my-component** inside and that directive has inside as well the directve **inner-directive**. the issue is that the button `<button class="btn btn-default center-block" ng-click="$ctrl.onSelectionChange({items_list: $ctrl.selectedItems})">Button</button>` function is not working. is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The function is indeed defined, but the callback I assigned is never reached.

Comment: Even if I cancel the inner-directive, and using a simple template as: '<html><button ...></html>' it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. While invoking the modal, I used a template used a component in this template. To the component, I passed a callback that is defined in the '$ctrl'. The problem was that the modal defined its own scope and couldn't reached this $ctrl. So I defined a controller to the modal, and called through it the function I needed. This is my solution, I highlighted the changes and adds:

calling-component-controller.js:

```
function CallingComponentCtrl(toastr, $scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    ....

   $ctrl.myFoo = function(items_list) {
        alert("This is never happening");
    };


    $ctrl.onPress = function (event) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            template: '<my-component on-selection-change="$ctrl.myNewFoo(items_list)"></my-component>',
            **controllerAs: '$ctrl',**
            windowClass: 'modal-window',
            **controller: function($uibModalInstance){
                var $ctrl = this;
                $ctrl.myNewFoo= function(items_list) {
                    $uibModalInstance.close(items_list);
                };
            }**
        });
        **modalInstance.result.then(function(items_list) {
              $ctrl.myFoo(items_list);
          });**
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $compile service

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  var template = $compile('<div class="container-fluid"> <inner-directive><button class="btn btn-default center-block" ng-click="$ctrl.onSelectionChange({items_list: $ctrl.selectedItems})">Button</button> </inner-directive> </div>')(scope);
  element.append(template);
}
```

Remember to inject the compile service to the directive function

Comment: It now seems that the template is not loaded. I commented out the original template attribute, added your suggestion and now nothing is up.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your child component to this:

```
.component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div class="container-fluid"> <inner-directive><button class="btn btn-default center-block" ng-click="$ctrl.onSelectionChange({items_list: $ctrl.selectedItems})">Button</button> </inner-directive> </div>',
    bindings: {
        $router: '<'
    },
    require: {
        parent: '^^CallingComponent'
    },
    controller: MyComponentController
});
```

With require you inherit the parent controller.
Then in the init function you can make the call:

```
function MyComponentController(MyService, $filter, $log, $q) {

    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.parent.myFoo(items_list);
    }

    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.$routerOnActivate = function () {};
    $ctrl.selectedItems = [];
}
```

--Old answer
Try changing the template to:

```
<my-component on-selection-change="$ctrl.myFoo(items_list)"></my-component>
```

You're calling it from the $scope when it's declared as a controller function.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is indeed configured with $ctrl.myFoo.
I edited it

Comment: @orizis try with require, see above

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I'm gonna try it tomorrow. One thing I don't understand, is where does onSelectionChange is defined? Shouldn't I bind it? Also, what is happening in onInit? Thanks again, Ori

Comment: $onInit is like a constructor for your component. So you inherit the parent controller and bind it to a local attribute of your component. Then you can just use anything declared in the parent component.

Comment: I think I might found the problem... My component is in a different module then my other component, can this be the reason the function is not being called?

Comment: Eventually this wasn't the issue. I posted my solution. Thanks for your help! @gyc